# Can´t understand this CSS hover construction

Tags: css, hover

Can anyone explain me this CSS line?

```
.thumbnail:hover div{

}
```

I don´t understand the "div" part...

Thanks!

Comment: In addition to the answers below you should read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators

Comment: Great material, thank you very much, Jon!

Answer (score 2):

You are styling the div descendant (inside) of an element with the class "thumbnail" upon which the mouse is pointed.

Comment: Thank you very much, MisteriosM!

Answer (score 0):

That's a selector which selects a `div` tag that is a descendant of any element having the `thumbnail` class that is currently in the hovered state.

Comment: Thank you very much, eskwayrd!